# getting a string from the user after getting int in C language

Tags: c, printf, scanf, gets

I can't understand why this code is not working properly:

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()
{
    char string [100];
    int a;
    printf(">");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf(">");
    gets(string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

This is a little part from a program that I had to build and I can't
 understand why after getting the value into a by scanf() function, the
 program just skip or not reading properly the string by gets()
 function. If you copy the code into compiler and tries to run you will
 understand what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

The `%d` specifier doesn't eat the newline (or other blanks for that matter). Try this:

```
scanf("%d ", &a);
         ^
```

That space makes `scanf` throw away all the blanks until a non-blank. Incidentally, your question is remarcably similar to this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html).

---

- Don't use `gets`, it's so bad it's not even in the language anymore.
  Use `fgets` instead
- Don't trust anyone suggesting `fflush(stdin)` for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to read a sentence composed with spaces (after any scanf's), modify your the scanf to:

```
scanf(" [^\n]", mystring);
       ^ Space here.
```

Look your example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char mystring[100];
    int a;

    printf(">");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf(">");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", mystring);

    printf("Number:%d\nString: %s\n", a, mystring);

    return 0;
}
```